# Sign of reversible work done

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

Consider a piston such that it is in mechanical equilibrium with its surroundings. If I pull the piston (reversible work) then the work done by me would be positive. If I push the piston, again work is done by me. However, in one case positive work is considered to be done on the gas inside piston, while it is negative in the other case. If I pull the piston, negative reversible work will be done on the gas -- does it mean that the gas is working on me? I know that I must be making a mistake, but what?

Comment: if you pull and release the piston it goes back, the same if you push

Comment: All three answers by Bob D, QPhysl, and Phillip Wood are in the same direction and help me understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

"If I pull the piston (reversible work) [beyond the equilibrium point] then the work done by me would be positive." This is work that you do against the atmosphere surrounding the cylinder and piston. There is also a contribution to this work from the expanding gas in the cylinder. It helps you pull out the piston.

When you pull out the piston, enlarging the cylinder volume by $\Delta V$,

Work done by you + $P_{\text{gas}}\Delta V=P_{\text{atmos}}\Delta V$.

$P_{\text{gas}}\Delta V$ is work done BY the gas. $P_{\text{gas}}$ is always positive, so if $\Delta V$ is positive  the work done by the gas is positive, and if $\Delta V$ is negative, the work done by the gas is negative, that is positive work is done ON the gas.

$P_{\text{atmos}}\Delta V$ is work done ON the atmosphere: positive if $\Delta V$ is positive (ie. the piston is moved out), negative if $\Delta V$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

I find the terms "work done by/to/on" somewhat confusing. If we use the definition of work: $$W=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}\,dt=\int_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}$$
We can see what we are referring to more easily. Here the path or curve through space that indexes the integral, $C$, is just a one-dimensional path from the starting point of the piston to the ending point of the piston during compression/decompression.

There are two forces acting, the internal force, which is from the pressure. If we imagine *we* are pushing the piston inwards (which I will call the negative $x-$direction) then we have: $$\mathbf{F}_\text{int.}=P\mathbf{A}=PA\,\mathbf{\hat{x}}$$
That is, it pushes outwards (in the positive $x-$direction). The external force is us pushing, which gives: $$\mathbf{F}_{\text{ext.}}=-F_{\text{ext.}}\mathbf{\hat{x}}$$
If we instead pull it, the sign will change: $$\mathbf{F}_{\text{ext.}}=+F_{\text{ext.}}\mathbf{\hat{x}}$$
There will also be a pressure term from the outside air but I'll include the associated force into the external force.

So the "work done by the gas" is: $$W=\int_C\mathbf{F}_\text{int.}\cdot d\mathbf{x}=\int_{V_i}^{V_f} P\, dV$$
The rest just depends on the semantics of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you push or pull on the piston you do positive work. That's because in both cases the direction of your force is the same as the direction of the displacement. When something does positive work, it transfers energy to something else.

When you pull on the piston you are doing work displacing the atmospheric. You are transferring energy to the atmosphere. At the same time, because you are reducing the external pressure against the gas, you are allowing it (the system) to expand and the system do positive work displacing the atmosphere. As far as the system is concerned, you and the atmosphere together constitute its surroundings.

When you push on the piston you are doing positive work compressing the system (gas). At the same time, you are allowing the atmosphere to expand against the system doing positive work compressing the system. Again, as far as the system is concerned, you and the atmosphere together constitute its surroundings.

So when is negative work done?

Negative work is done when the direction of the force is opposite the direction of the displacement. When something does negative work, energy is transferred to it. When the piston is pushed and does positive work compressing the gas, the gas does negative work since the force it exerts on the piston is opposite the displacement of the piston and thus energy is transferred to the gas.

Similarly, when the piston is pulled doing positive work against the atmosphere, the atmosphere does negative work since its force is opposite to the its displacement. Energy is transferred to the atmosphere.

Hope this helps.